# How to find out if an XML document contains a certain element (by tag name)?

Tags: javascript, xml

Suppose I have downloaded a valid XML document via Ajax (var docum = request.responseXML;). Now how do I find out if it contains a certain element (by tag name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getElementsByTagName` method, e.g.

```
var scripts = docum.getElementsByTagName('script');
if (scripts.length > 0) {
  // contains.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(xml.getElementsByTagName("myTag").length > 0){
    alert("myTag is here");
}else{
    alert("myTag is NOT here")
}
```